# Installing GRUB 2 Within Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-partition

I need to reinstall GRUB 2 because Windows has removed/overridden​ it. I am tempted to install it right we're Windows has its efi boot partition but I may need windows later for something and would like to just let GRUB 2 handle booting Windows too if needed, so I really don't want to break the boot process for Windows. Should I create a new partition for it? If so does it matter where the partition is located? Also is it safe to use this guide within a active Ubuntu installation?

How to Repair, Restore & Reinstall GRUB 2 With A Ubuntu Live CD
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: If installed in UEFI mode then what you linked doesn't apply and it probably is so simple as to put Ubuntu as first priority again in UEFI settings.

Comment: That wouldn't work because my BIOS does not read EX4 partitions.

Comment: **It doesn't need to, The ESP (EFI System Partition is always FAT32.** Now is clear you don't know what I'm talking about, but you *should* (when installing a OS, any OS) and you *must* (if dual/multi booting).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792863/install-ubuntu-on-seperate-hard-drive#comment1193198_792863

Comment: @MichaelBay "It doesn't need to, The ESP (EFI System Partition is always FAT32. Now is clear you don't know what I'm talking about, but you should (when installing a OS, any OS) and you must (if dual/multi booting)." Wow. You. Are. Amazing. You know what, that's great and all but Ubuntu runs on EXT4 and my BIOS does NOT have some simple easy button saying "Ubuntu Partition" as you must think. "https://askubuntu.com/questions/792863/install-ubuntu-on-seperate-hard-drive#comment1193198_792863" As I already said, Ubuntu IS installed. Windows placed it's bootloader in the spot where GRUB 2 was.

Comment: It's quite simple: Help us help you, it all starts there. You have one of two situations (we don't know because instead of providing useful information you insist in doing something else, ck. Dunning–Kruger): 1. With *BIOS/Legacy/CSM installs, an Windows update may have overwritten the MBR and installed the Windows bootloader instead of grub. To get back grub you need to do this: /questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows or (...)

Comment: 2. With **UEFI** installs, the some can happen in a *major* Windows update but it's just a matter of giving it first priority again in the boot order at UEFI setting (varies a lot from one brand to another). Alternatively, there's the not-so-elegant solution of installing EasyUEFI in Windows and managing the boot entries with it. This is why you need to be aware of the differences *and* include such info in the question in the first place. The procedure is completely different!

Comment: Incomplete link above. For BIOS/Legacy/CSM: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Sorry for being rude earlier. It looks like the only part that applies to me is "grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub # In order to find and add windows to grub menu." I'm going to try it and see what happens. Alternatively I could build another PC to test on. I'm still not sure what you mean by "giving it first priority again in the boot order at UEFI setting" giving what priority? I don't want to boot windows and it's the only boot option. I'd appreciate a little bit more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I mean there's a huge difference between the 40+ years old BIOS and UEFI and you must know which one you have and how the OSes have been installed. To complicate even more, most UEFI enabled machines have a compatibility mode (CSM) that allows the installation in the old way (for compatibility with OSes that do not support it).

Comment: Oh I can't believe I left that out I thought I mentioned I have a UEFI system. Sorry I'm still one of those people who say BIOS when they mean UEFI. Yeah I setup everything when I installed Ubuntu (you know, installing GRUB 2 and disabling secure boot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

"For BIOS/Legacy/CSM: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)" I followed instructions here within my gparted USB and got grub working again.